# Windows Server 2012 folder share without active directory

Tags: permissions, file-sharing, windows-server-2012

I am having a really hard time figuring out how to effectively set up folder sharing with Windows Server 2012. I have four servers all collocated in a data center. Each server has two ethernet connections, one for access over the internet, and one connecting the four to a local LAN for data transfers and access to SQL data. One of the servers is my dedicated backup machine. I have set up folder sharing on this server but am not familiar with user permissions and how to get this set up correctly.

-I do not have active directory or any other type of user management. The only users set up on these servers are the admin user to login and make changes. Everything else is handled by other applications (SQL Server users, ASP.NET users for web site, etc.)

-I want my shared folder to only be accessible by the servers on the LAN and not accessible over the internet to random people

-I need full read/write access to the shared folder by all machines

With this said, I am not much of a computer administrator. I learn as I go and know just enough to get everything set up for what we need. Think of all the servers as working independent and not connected to a domain controller or anything. I just hit the IP addresses of the services I need. All servers have the same administrator user login, but I'm assuming the servers see these as different since they show up as computername\username. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Setup a local user on the server.
- Set up the share and give that local user the desired permissions (to the share and to the file folder being shared).
- When you go to access the share from other computers you'll need to use the login/password of the user account you added to the server.

Repeat for each server you want to setup a share on.

Depending on how you're accessing that share, you may need to specify the server's name as the "domain" you're logging into (ie: user name of "Server1/User1").

Comment: I tried doing this. For some reason I was able to perform a single backup (in Server Backup, the Backup Once option). I noticed I was able to do this by not providing any credentials or by entering the local username and password (local user of backup server). However, when I try to set up the Backup Schedule I am hit with the user is not recognized on the local machine. I do not understand windows authentication at all, are they only designed to work with active directory?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually had the same username on all machines but couldn't get this to work initially. When I was prompted for the username and password to access the share I was entering the ComputerName\UserName and was getting the error of user did not exist on local machine. When I entered just the username everything is working normally.

As for limiting the share to my local LAN only; From what I can tell if I simply change the firewall rules on port 445 to only accept connections from my other servers IP addresses I should accomplish the goal of limiting my shares to the local LAN.